# Using classes to show/hide rows in a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table named "tasksTable". I can do a search in the table to filter my preferred results. So if I do a search for "bob" in my textfield, it will hide all the rows and then show the rows that have the "bob" results. What i'm trying to accomplish is filtering out that subset of data. Each row has a class of ".status-All" and then depending on the status it also has a class of ".status-Open" or ".status-Closed". How do I show/hide within the presented results the open or closed status. Here's the code I'm using but it doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
  $(document).on('click','.showStatus',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var oSel = $(this).html();
    var status = $(this).attr('data-status');
    
    $('#statusG>a').html('Showing: '+oSel+' <span class="caret"></span>');

// The following ignores current displayed data. It basically resets it and un-searches the previous search and show's all closed regardless of the status selected
        
        if(status=='Closed'){
            $('.status-Open').hide();
            $('.status-Closed').show();
        } else if (status=='Open'){
            $('.status-Closed').hide();
            $('.status-Open').show();
        };
        
        if(status=='All')
        $('.status-All').show();
    
  });   

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" id="tasksTable" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 1898px;"><colgroup><col style="width: 28px;"><col style="width: 301px;"><col style="width: 109px;"><col style="width: 583px;"><col style="width: 300px;"><col style="width: 123px;"><col style="width: 83px;"><col style="width: 83px;"><col style="width: 83px;"><col style="width: 123px;"><col style="width: 56px;"><col style="width: 27px;"></colgroup>
  
  <thead><tr class="size-row" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 51.5px;"><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="&nbsp;" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Client" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Type" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Description" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Owners" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Opened By" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Entry Date" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Due Date" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Closed Date" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Closed By" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Status" style="height: 51.5px;"></th><th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 51.5px;"></th></tr></thead><tbody>


  <tr class="status-All status-Open" style="display: table-row;">
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-primary but_editTaskModal" data-taskid="184" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=489">Company 1</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Implementation</td>
    <td><a href="/clients_detail.asp?clientID=489#tasks">Full Implementation - Internal</a></td>
    <td>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="99" data-taskid="184">Bob Smith <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        
        

        
        </td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">5/20/2019</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">10/18/2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">Open</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-danger but-deleteTask" data-taskid="184" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="status-All status-Closed" style="display: table-row;">
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-primary but_editTaskModal" data-taskid="185" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=506">Company 2</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Implementation</td>
    <td><a href="/clients_detail.asp?clientID=506#tasks">Full implementaiton</a></td>
    <td>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="99" data-taskid="185">Bob Smith <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        
        
        </td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">5/20/2019</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">3/29/2019</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">9/15/2020</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">Closed</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-danger but-deleteTask" data-taskid="185" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="status-All status-Open" style="display: table-row;">
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-primary but_editTaskModal" data-taskid="186" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
    <td nowrap=""><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=488">ABB Group [ABBG]</a></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Implementation</td>
    <td><a href="/clients_detail.asp?clientID=488#tasks">Audit of ABB Mexico</a></td>
    <td>
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="99" data-taskid="186">Jack Spades <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        
        
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="130" data-taskid="186">Vikki Van Vliet <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        
        </td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">5/20/2019</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">10/15/2017</td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
    <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">Open</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-danger but-deleteTask" data-taskid="186" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
<fthfoot style="display: table-footer-group; border-spacing: 0px; height: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; visibility: hidden;"><fthtr style="display: table-row; border-spacing: 0px; height: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;"><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd><fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd></fthtr></fthfoot></table>
```

Comment: hi, can you create working demo code ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly, you want to be able to hide table rows?
I added a reset button at the top of your table. Codepen: https://codepen.io/kbrfuller/pen/WNGrVpv

HTML

```
<button id="RESET">RESET-LIST</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" id="tasksTable" style="table-layout: fixed; min-width: 1898px;">
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 28px;">
    <col style="width: 301px;">
    <col style="width: 109px;">
    <col style="width: 583px;">
    <col style="width: 300px;">
    <col style="width: 123px;">
    <col style="width: 83px;">
    <col style="width: 83px;">
    <col style="width: 83px;">
    <col style="width: 123px;">
    <col style="width: 56px;">
    <col style="width: 27px;">
  </colgroup>

  <thead>
    <tr class="size-row" aria-hidden="true" style="height: 51.5px;">
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="&nbsp;" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Client" style="height: 51.5px;">Client</th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Type" style="height: 51.5px;">Type</th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Description" style="height: 51.5px;">Desc</th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Owners" style="height: 51.5px;">Owners</th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Opened By" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Entry Date" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Due Date" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Closed Date" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Closed By" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="Status" style="height: 51.5px;">Status</th>
      <th class="floatThead-col" aria-label="" style="height: 51.5px;"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="status-All status-Open" style="display: table-row;">
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-primary but_editTaskModal" data-taskid="184" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
      <td nowrap=""><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=489">Company 1</a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Implementation</td>
      <td><a href="/clients_detail.asp?clientID=489#tasks">Full Implementation - Internal</a></td>
      <td>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="99" data-taskid="184">Bob Smith <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

      </td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">5/20/2019</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">10/18/2017</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">Open</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-danger but-deleteTask" data-taskid="184" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="status-All status-Closed" style="display: table-row;">
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-primary but_editTaskModal" data-taskid="185" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
      <td nowrap=""><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=506">Company 2</a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Implementation</td>
      <td><a href="/clients_detail.asp?clientID=506#tasks">Full implementaiton</a></td>
      <td>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="99" data-taskid="185">Bob Smith <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

      </td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">5/20/2019</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">3/29/2019</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">9/15/2020</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">Closed</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-danger but-deleteTask" data-taskid="185" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="status-All status-Open" style="display: table-row;">
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-primary but_editTaskModal" data-taskid="186" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
      <td nowrap=""><a href="clients_detail.asp?clientID=488">ABB Group [ABBG]</a></td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">Implementation</td>
      <td><a href="/clients_detail.asp?clientID=488#tasks">Audit of ABB Mexico</a></td>
      <td>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="99" data-taskid="186">Jack Spades <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs but-removeOwner" type="button" style="margin-top:4px; margin-right:4px;" data-auditorid="130" data-taskid="186">Vikki Van Vliet <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>

      </td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">5/20/2019</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;">10/15/2017</td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;"></td>
      <td nowrap="" style="text-align: center;">Open</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="text-danger but-deleteTask" data-taskid="186" style="margin-right:5px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  <fthfoot style="display: table-footer-group; border-spacing: 0px; height: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; visibility: hidden;">
    <fthtr style="display: table-row; border-spacing: 0px; height: 0px; border-collapse: collapse;">
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
      <fthtd style="display: table-cell; height: 0px; width: auto;"></fthtd>
    </fthtr>
  </fthfoot>
</table>
```

CSS

```
thead { background: lightblue; }
```

JQUERY

```
$(function() {
  
  // RESET ROWS and SHOW all
  $('#RESET').on('click', function(e) {
     $('tbody tr').show();
  });
  
  $('body').on('click', '.but-removeOwner', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var oSel = $(this).text();
    //alert (oSel);
    
    $('.but-removeOwner').each(function () {
      if ( $(this).text() === oSel ) {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        //alert ( $(this).text() );
      }
    });
    
  });
  
}); //end $(function())
```

Comment: Appreciate the response. My issue isn't hiding or resetting, my issue is (using your example), once i click on a name to remove all rows using that name. How do I take the left over rows and show only the ones that have a status of 'closed'. Again, WITH the REMAINING rows. If there was a way i could say: onclick (take a visible rows and hide all that have a status of 'closed'). but again... ONLY the VISIBLE rows